# Maximum likelihood estimator doesn't exist

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I was reading a paper, and the last paragraph it says

> For example, consider the density function $$p_{(\theta,\sigma)}(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\large{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\theta)^2}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}e^{\large{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\theta)^2}} $$
> of the sequence of independent and identically distributed chance variable $X_1,X_2, \dots$ Here $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma > 0$. It is easy to see that the supremum of the likelihood function is almost always infinite , no MLE exists [...]

So, the likelihood function would be $\prod_{i=1}^np_{(\theta,\sigma)}(x_i)$ by the i.i.d. condition, but I don't see why this wouldn't have maximum. Even the case where $\theta$ is fixed and $\sigma$ is near to $0$, the function is close to $0$. Can I get some insights please?

Comment: Usually "it is easy to see" means "it is *not* easy to see"...

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @callculus I mean, I don't see why this would be different from the calculation of the MLE for the normal distribution, as I said in the comment on kimchi's answer

Comment: @Ejrionm I wouldn´t tackle the problem by "seeing". I would write down the MLE and see what I can do.

Comment: @callculus I think the MLE is $$\sum_{i=1}^n \log \left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\large{-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\theta)^2}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}e^{\large{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x_i-\theta)^2}} \right)$$

Comment: This is the log likelihood, not the $\theta$ and $\sigma$ that maximize it, that is, not the MLE.  The expression you wrote is unbounded as a function of $\theta$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, sorry, I should have said the likelihood function, since the MLE shouldn't exist, cause that's what I want to prove. So the key part of this is the sum of those exponentials?

Comment: The "key" part is that the reciprocals of tiny numbers are huge numbers.  The term $\exp(-(x_i-\theta)^2/2\sigma^2)/\sigma$ blows up when $\theta=x_i$ and $\sigma$ is tiny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likelihood function, as a function of the two variables $\theta$ and $\sigma$, takes on arbitrarily large values when evaluated at $\theta=x_1$ and at $\sigma$ very close to $0$. Because of the division by $\sigma$ in the second term in your formula for the density.  Other values of $\theta$ close to any of the $x_i$ and with $\sigma\ge\min_i|x_i-\theta|$ will similarly give rise to large values of the likelihood.

Comment: But why can you fix the value of $\theta$ at $x_1$? I mean, is (kinda) the same p.d.f. as the normal distribution, and for the normal distribution we does have the MLE, why is this example different?